# UITabBar strange behavior first initialization in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

As mentioned in the title, I have a problem with a custom TabBar when I initialize it the first time.

The TabBarController has five relationships in the storyboard and it is not Initial View Controller.

When App is launched I set a TabBarController as a rootViewController, but the first time I launch the App and the TabBar doesn't recognize touch, no didSelect called; relaunch App and the TabBar work properly. I have no one log of error or warning.

The configuration of TabBar was the same for the first launch and for the second.

Edit:
That happened **only in the simulator**, not in a real device: I need to resolve for Apple Review that uses a simulator.

SplashScreenViewController is my Initial view controller, here I verify that the user is not logged in, than I set LoginViewController as a rootViewController:

```
    let login = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginStoryboardID") as! LoginViewController
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = login
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

After the user has logged in I set my TabBarController as a rootViewController:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    tabBar = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarControllerStoryboardID") as? UITabBarController
    tabBar?.tabBar.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
    tabBar? .tabBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    tabBar?.delegate = self

    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = tabBar
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: *"When App is launched I set a TabBarController as a rootViewController"* --- how are you doing that? It sounds like the first and second launch are **not** identical.

Comment: You can see my edit with the code: first and second time was identical for sure, and in all real device work.. that behavior its only in a simulator

Comment: Where have you added the above code ?

Comment: @chirag90 in a method that was called after user has logged in. I don't think it's a "viewDidAppear" or "viewDidLoad" problem

Comment: have you tried to add the code in `didFinishLaunching` in appDelegate.

Comment: No, it's a complex application which requires a mandatory Login and I have to call rest services and prepare database before retrieving TabBar from the storyboard and viewing it. didFinishLaunching is called too early. Sorry for the repetition but its only a simulator problem, I don't think its an implementation problem..

Comment: @weso - to get help with this, you probably need to put together a [mcve].

Comment: @DonMag Yes I think so too, I'm trying to separate the affected part, it takes some time

Comment: @weso dismiss the previous rootviewController when change a root viewController try this
 previousRootViewController.dismiss(animated: false, completion: {
                previousRootViewController.view.removeAllSubviews()
            })